# FlashDevelop (Flex/AS3) and localized compiler messages

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

I am completely new to the whole FlashDevelop/Flash/etc toolchain, but wanted to do some experimenting. I installed FlashDevelop and Flex SDK on my laptop, and thinks worked out just fine, except for one thing: the compiler messages are localized!

Messages like "gebruik van een niet-gedefinieerde eigenschap" (Dutch.. sort of) are limiting my productivity. I don't recognize them because they look nothing like what I'm used to in any other programming environment, as a proper sentence they make even less sense than English error messages, and I certainly can't google them properly.

Now I've already seen there are a couple of xml files and java/mxmlc/fcsh/etc configs I can tweak, but nothing so far helped.

Please help me restore sanity and en_US/1033/etc! Thanks...

---

***Edit*** Setting my windows locale to English through the control panel, then restarting FlashDevelop, did result in English error messages from Flex. So hurray, I've got a usable workaround. I'd still like the two to be unrelated though, as a developer a fiddle with those settings all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting my windows locale to English through the control panel, then restarting FlashDevelop, did result in English error messages from Flex.

I someone comes up with a better solution, I'll gladly accept that answer in stead of this one...

Answer (score 4):

Modify **jvm.config** file located in the same folder as your **mxmlc.exe**
by adding on **java.args** line the following option:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
```

Detailed explanation is [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/1/internationalization_flex_short/internationalization_flex_short7.html#81676).

Comment: Tried that before (just re-checked), doesn't help. My java.args look like this: 
java.args=-Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US

Answer (score 2):

Goto `Tools | Program Settings` (press F10) and select `Flash Develop` from the left panel. Scroll down to the `Misc` heading - the last option is `Selected Locale`. If en_US is not there, then you have a problem - you might have to download the correct locale version again.

Comment: +1 for the sensible reply, but alas: that specific Selected Locale setting is already set to en_US. I guess I just have to fiddle around some more.